# HTML/PHP email form not working

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I've made a very simple email form in HTML that should be running a php script to send an email to my email address:

```
<form id="emailForm" action="sendMail.php" method="post">
    Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="your name"><br>
    E-mail:<br>
    <input type="text" name="email" value="your email"><br>
    Message:<br>
    <textarea cols="40" rows="5" name="message">your message</textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

My php script looks like this:

```
<?php
// This function checks for email injection. Specifically, it checks for carriage returns - typically used by spammers to inject a CC list.
function isInjected($str) {
    $injections = array('(\n+)',
    '(\r+)',
    '(\t+)',
    '(%0A+)',
    '(%0D+)',
    '(%08+)',
    '(%09+)'
    );
    $inject = join('|', $injections);
    $inject = "/$inject/i";
    if(preg_match($inject,$str)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

// Load form field data into variables.
$name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
$email_address = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$comments = $_REQUEST['message'] ;

// If the user tries to access this script directly, redirect them to feedback form,
if (!isset($_REQUEST['email'])) {
header( "Location: contact.html" );
}

// If the form fields are empty, redirect to the error page.
elseif (empty($email_address) || empty($comments) || empty($name)) {
header( "Location: error_message.html" );
}

// If email injection is detected, redirect to the error page.
elseif ( isInjected($email_address) ) {
header( "Location: error_message.html" );
}

// If we passed all previous tests, send the email!
else {
mail( "r.krishnan1@umiami.edu", "Message From Your Website!",
  $comments, "From: $email_address" );
header( "Location: thank_you.html" );
}
?>
```

As I am quite new to scripting, this script is mostly taken from example code, but it all appears to make sense to me. The html page that the form is located in and the php file are both uploaded to the same directory on the server. However, when I press the "submit" button on the form, I am simply taken in my browser to a text version of the php file itself (ie I just go to the php file in my directory) and no email is sent. Why might this be happening?

Comment: Maybe this is a dump question, but did you configured a web server for your project?

Comment: Your contact form is open to mail header injection, it's easy for spammers to add extra headers, and your `isInjected` function contains bad practice: you should *white-list* mail addresses, not filter out possible maliciously used characters.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run your PHP program by having your browser visit an HTTP(S) URL provided by a web server that supports PHP and is configured to execute it for the file you have placed your PHP code in.

Either:

- You are loading the file directly from your filesystem instead of through a webserver *or*
- You don't have your server configured for PHP for the file you are loading (a default PHP configuration will expect the code to be in a file with a `.php` extension)

Comment: I'm using nearlyfreespeech.net as my server. All of the .html files for my website are uploaded to the home directory in my account of the server. This is also where I've put my .php file (sendMail.php). So it seems that the browser IS visiting that URL, but the script is not actually being run? As far as I can tell, the server I'm on is configured for PHP, so I'm still not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
$headers = 'From: '.$email_address . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: '.$email_address . "\r\n" ;

mail( "r.krishnan1@umiami.edu", "Message From Your Website!", $comments,  $headers);
```

Comment: Don't encourage people to add that infamous `X-Mailer: PHP` header: it's useless and even dangerous, as it might attract hackers.

Comment: @Marcel Korpel Thanks! Removed that header